# ionic 2, two maps in app conflicts

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, maps

I have this provider:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonService} from "./common-service";
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

declare var google;

@Injectable()
export class Maps{
   load_map(selector:any,zoom:number,center_coords:any = {lat: this.lat ,lng: this.lng}){


    this.lat = center_coords.lat;
    this.lng = center_coords.lng;

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center_coords.lat, center_coords.lng);

        let mapOptions = {zoom: zoom};
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(selector, mapOptions);

      if(this.map){

        return resolve(this.map);
      }else{
        return reject({error:"can not load maps"});
      }

    })

  }

 set_center(lat :number = this.lat,lng :number = this.lng){
     let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
     this.map.setCenter(latLng);
  }
}
```

i use a factory in my app module:

```
{
   provide: 'Maps', 
   useFactory: () => 
      new Maps(), 
     deps: []
},
```

In my page i import the service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-report',
  templateUrl: 'report.html'
})

export class ReportPage{
 public map:any;
 @ViewChild('reportmap') mapElement :ElementRef;

   construct(@Inject('Maps') mapsfactory){
      this.map = mapsfactory;//this is a new instance always 
      this.map.load_map(mapElement,16,{lat:123,lng:123});
      this.map.set_center(234,234);
   }
}
```

other page:

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'other-page',
      templateUrl: 'other-page.html'
    })

    export class OtherPage{
     public map:any;
     @ViewChild('map') mapElement :ElementRef;//diferent input

       construct(@Inject('Maps') mapsfactory){
          this.map = mapsfactory;
          this.map.load_map(mapElement,16,{lat:123,lng:123});
       }
    }
```

In app init works fine, but if change the center in second instance (OtherPage) using a click or other event to change center affects to ReportPage map, i try reset center to original position but not render correctly, use the factory to create two diferent instances of maps but doesn't work, this problem only appear when change center of map. elementRef are diferents id and input attribute, all is diferent between the instances! on browser it´s ok, this problem only appear in android device, i newbie using angular 2 and ionic 2, i think android optimizes maps by creating a single instance, Any idea or similar problem to resolve together?
I think in a bad solution but I could not do it; reload tab 0 (reportpage) after finish work in tab 1 (otherPage) and reload after click on tab 0.

Comment: Make sure to destroy your map at ngOnDestroy()

Comment: @JoeriShoeby the problem is, i need both maps in diferent views but the map in second view affects map in first view, in browser works perfectly but in device not because create only one instance of my provider and i need two instances.

Comment: So destroy it when you switch views, or add the service to your components providers: [] array, which results into  a new instance of that service.